# Heckscher-Ohlin with non homothetic preferences

Tags: international-trade, preferences, competitive-equilibrium

Can someone tell me how I can show with an example that the Heckscher-Ohlin result does not necessarily hold when preferences are not homothetic.
I was asked if it similar as a case in which the preference are heterogeneous, but that would obviously be a different type of preference.

Would anyone know how to proceed?

Cheers,
James

Comment: 1. If the preferences in the other question were homothetic and heterogeneous, that would be different. However only heterogeneity is required. 2. I recommend you read our FAQ on self-study/homework problems.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out, but is there a way you could explain it to me how heterogeneity would show that the Hecksher-Ohlin theory would not hold? I'm really not getting there and could use the help

Comment: 1. Have you read the FAQ? 2. Do you understand why Hecksher-Ohlin theory works with identical homothetic preferences? Please answer both questions, not just the one you like.

Comment: Yes I read the FAQ, and I would have answered the question if it was homothetical and identical which is the only way I have ever seen it. I know that in normal terms preferences are assumed to be identical and homothetical and that we do that because it eliminates noise and like that we only focus on factor endowment, what I don't understand is how its possible to prove that non homothetical and heteregenous preference could still be used with the Heckscher-Ohlin model. Thank you for helping me out, really stuck